# Continuum function eventually constant

Tags: set-theory

Let $\kappa \geq 2$ be a cardinal and $\lambda$ an infinite cardinal. Say $\lambda < cf(\kappa^{<\lambda})$. I'm trying to show that then the continuum function is eventually constant below $\lambda$ with value $\chi$.

I try this as follows:

Assume that the continuum function is not eventually constant below $\lambda$. So for every $\gamma < \lambda$ there is some $\delta = \delta(\gamma)$  so that $2^\delta > \chi$ and $\delta < \gamma < \lambda$. ($\star$)

Keeping in mind that $\kappa^{<\lambda} = sup\{ \kappa^\theta: \theta < \lambda,\theta \text{ cardinal}\}$ I want to construct a sequence $(\xi_\alpha: \alpha < \lambda)$ via ($\star$) which behaves like the $\kappa^\theta$ in order to get a contradiction. Yet I struggle with the details.

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @FShrike Thanks for the welcome. Might I ask you, is my question above banal?

Comment: I’m afraid I have absolutely no idea. I upvoted your question because it seemed interesting, but set theory is one of the areas of mathematics I have never really studied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to prove isn't correct.

Say GCH holds, and let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal and let $\lambda = \aleph_\omega$ (or any limit cardinal less than $\kappa$, really). We have $$cf(\kappa^{<\lambda})=cf(\kappa)=\kappa>\lambda$$ and the continuum function is not eventually constant below any limit cardinal.

What is true is that if $\lambda < cf(\kappa^{<\lambda}),$ then the function $\mu\mapsto \kappa^{\mu}$ is eventually constant below $\lambda.$ If it weren't then we'd have $cf(\kappa^{<\lambda})=cf(\lambda)\le \lambda.$

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Would it be correct to assume that for any $\sigma < \kappa$ the  function $\mu \mapsto \sigma^\mu$ still cannot fulfill the statement, as your stated counterexample could be applied again in this case?

Comment: @lowcard yes, in the sense that we could choose a limit cardinal $\lambda$ between $\sigma$ and $\kappa$ (and then it’s pretty much the same thing since that function becomes the continuum function above $\sigma$.)